# jssor: bug in full-width-slider.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Resize works fine except when I maximise the screen, the navigator arrow is missing at the right and the select navigator at the bottom.

http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.html

1) Can you confirm that this is a bug?

2) If not, how can I fix this?

[image: missing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah I see the error, too. I can tell it's placed correctly if I turn off display: none; but it seems to be hidden once it gets past 880px from the left side. It seems to be because `#slider1_container > div > div` is getting `overflow: hidden;` written inline. Locate what's doing this in your JavaScript and turn it off. If you must, hackishly use `!important` for a quick fix to be revisited later.